# I want to change my url (htaccess)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url (htaccess)
from :

```
www.website.com/page.php?id=128
```

to :

```
www.website.com/?a=128
```

and

```
www.website.com/images.php?id=128
```

to :

```
www.website.com/?i=128
```

thank you

Comment: So what about just do it?

Comment: Well welcome to SO, but we have some rules for Questions, and one is: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)i=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /images.php?id=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /page.php?id=%1 [L]
```