# .htaccess - how to replace old urls and then redirect to new urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

in htaccess, i want to change an old url like this :

```
http://olddomain.com/n/1234/permatitle
```

to

```
http://newdomain.com/news/1234/permatitle
```

but any ways i tried, redirect not work.

Comment: Since this seems pretty straight forward there is little sense in us repeating the answers already given. If none of all those really did not work for you, then we need to find out why. For that you need to post what you actually tried. And what you observed with those attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to change my url (htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323435/i-want-to-change-my-url-htaccess)